# Do you consider this design as an application layer on top of the CAN protocol?

Tags: protocol, can, bus

This is a follow up question from my previous question about 
[How do I program 2 CAN nodes to transmit continuously in succession?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84085/how-do-i-program-2-can-nodes-to-transmit-continuously-in-succession)

I'm planning to add another layer on top of the CAN protocol and I want to know this can be considered as a user-defined application layer. This is just for academic purposes. So here it is:

Considering a subset of the CAN network (Sensors serves only as examples): 
Node A: Collector-Node and displays data to the LCD
Node B: Get the coordinates of the GPS and transmit to node B.
Node C: Performs ADC to get the temperature of a test subject and transmits to node A.

Some definitions:

```
struct formalized_can{
   float latitude;
   float longtitude;
   float temperature;
 };
```

The top level functions are:

Node A:

```
getRecentUpdates(struct formalized_can);
```

Node B:

```
updateTemp(float temperature);
```

Node C:

```
updateGPS(float longitude, float latitude);
```

This are the functions that will be visible to the user of the library. The implementation is hidden from the user. Since application layer deals with messages, can this be considered as an application layer?